# How to open a screen from another screen which was already opened from a another screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

So I have a React Native app with a bottom tab navigation, in one of those tab screens I have an icons in the right header which leads me to a settings screen and for this I use stackNavigation but I also want to open another screen from this Settings screen - Account screen. How do I achieve this? Do I just use stack navigation again?

Comment: You can use history.push(newScreenURL)

Comment: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Comment: this will may help you....